# Error while installing droidcam

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, droidcam

After typing `sudo apt-get install droidcam`

i am getting error :-

```
Setting up droidcam (1.3-0ubuntu0) ...
tar: *.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dpkg: error processing package droidcam (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 droidcam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

output for **`sudo apt-cache policy droidcam`**

```
droidcam:
  Installed: 1.3-0ubuntu0
  Candidate: 1.3-0ubuntu0
  Version table:
 *** 1.3-0ubuntu0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/droidcam/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

how to solve this issue ?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy droidcam`

Comment: updated please look @A.B.

Comment: It looks almost as if you have droidcam installed already

Comment: Only a hint, remove droidcam and that will also cause problems. Give me a ping if you're stuck.

Comment: any reasons of down voting  this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the error you mentioned is 2nd state after 1st install trial.

- The first trial ends up with make/compilation error and removes the module source archives (without checking if build was successful).
- The next trials show missing kernel module source archive.

Here is the original error ([full log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12860441/)):

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`                                                                                                                                          
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic'                                                                                                                 
  LD      /opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/built-in.o                                                                                                                                        
  CC [M]  /opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.o                                                                                                                                 
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c: In function ‘attr_store_maxopeners’:                                                                                                     
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:456:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strict_strtoul’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   if (strict_strtoul(buf, 0, &curr))
   ^
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c: At top level:
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:2311:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
   .vidioc_s_std            = &vidioc_s_std,
   ^
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:2311:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘v4l2_loopback_ioctl_ops.vidioc_s_std’)
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:2331:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
   .vidioc_s_audio          = &vidioc_s_audio,
   ^
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:2331:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘v4l2_loopback_ioctl_ops.vidioc_s_audio’)
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:2333:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
   .vidioc_s_audout         = &vidioc_s_audout,
   ^
/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c:2333:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘v4l2_loopback_ioctl_ops.vidioc_s_audout’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:263: recipe for target '/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.o] Error 1
Makefile:1395: recipe for target '_module_/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/opt/droidcam/v4l2loopback] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To fix the original error, `strict_strtoul` was replaced with `kstrtoul`

1. Get source

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository -s ppa:paolorotolo/droidcam
   sudo apt-get update

   mkdir sand_box
   cd sand_box

   apt-get source droidcam
   cd droidcam-*/
   ```
2. Install build dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get builddep droiddeb
   sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper
   ```
3. Replace `strict_strtoul` with `kstrtoul` in:

   - droidcam-v4l2-x64.tar.gz : /v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c
   - droidcam-v4l2-x86.tar.gz : /v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c
4. Build & install

   ```
   debbuild -d -uc
   sudo dpkg -i ../droidcam_*.deb
   ```

---

Another way, without debian package rebuild:

1. After you have tried installing it and got the error. If not yet, run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install droidcam
   ```
2. Go to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Open its package with archive-manager and extract both `droidcam-v4l2-*.tar.gz` files (or just needed arch)
3. Replace `strict_strtoul` with `kstrtoul` in:

   - droidcam-v4l2-x64.tar.gz : /v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c
   - droidcam-v4l2-x86.tar.gz : /v4l2loopback/v4l2loopback-dc.c
4. Move both archives to /opt/droidcam/

   ```
   sudo mv droidcam-v4l2-*.tar.gz /opt/droidcam/
   ```
5. Run installation again to rebuild it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install droidcam
   ```

**References:**

- [Patchwork [dpdk-dev] eal: replace strict_strtoul with kstrtoul](http://dpdk.org/dev/patchwork/patch/952/)